# How can 【所】に【物】があります be converted to 【物】は【所】です?

Tags: grammar

Consider the following,

1. 机の上に本があります。
2. 本は机の上です。

What I don't understand is the second sentence which is another form for the first one. It is caused by the fact that there is no preposition に in the second one.

If you don't understand what I meant, let consider the following sentences. The first two sentences are understandable because they have English equivalents. But it is not the case for the last one.

- This is a book. これは本です。
- This book is red.　この本は赤いです。
- This book is on the table.　この本は机の上です。I never read and hear この本は机の上にです。in which there is に inserted between 机の上 and です.

Can anybody here explain why?

Comment: In fact, the で part comes from にて. The copula in Classical Japanese was なり, which was a contraction of にあり. But later て was inserted in between. That's origin of である and だ.

Comment: この本は机の上にです is "this book should be onto the desk".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say:

> 本はどこですか？ Where's the book?  (＝本はどこにありますか？)
>   机の上です。 It's on the desk.  (＝机の上にあります。)
>   本は机の上です。 The book is on the desk. (＝本は机の上にあります。)

and no one would think you're saying "The book is upper part of a desk".
Similar examples are:

> お父さんは二階です。 Dad is upstairs.
>   太郎くんは学校です。 Taro is away at school.
>   姉は今、ロンドンです。 My sister is in London now.

You can even say:

> 僕はウナギです。(I'll have eel.)
>   私はオレンジジュース。(I'll have orange juice.)

at a cafe or restaurant, and no one would think you're saying you're an eel or orange juice.

> *この本は机の上にです。

is incorrect.

Comment: How about 私がウナギです。?

Comment: Yeah, to ウナギのお客様(はどちらですか)?, you might respond with 私がウナギです, 私です, ウナギは私です, etc.

Comment: この本は机の上にです is a barely grammatical phrase you might use when you're really forced to distinguish "**to** the surface of the desk" and "**from** the surface of the desk".